# cloudfront cache invalidation fails in Circle CI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, aws-cli, circleci

I'm trying to create a cache invalidation from Circle CI but it fails each time with the following error:

```
An error occurred (IncompleteSignature) when calling the CreateInvalidation operation: 'xxxxxxxxx/20201215/us-east-1/cloudfront/aws4_request' not a valid key=value pair (missing equal-sign) in Authorization header: 'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=*********************/20201215/us-east-1/cloudfront/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=host;x-amz-date, Signature=xxxxxxxxxx'.
```

The command I launch is the following:

```
aws cloudfront create-invalidation --distribution-id XXXXXXXX --paths "/assets/texts/*"
```

It works fine on my machine using the same ACCESS_KEY and SECRET as the one configured on Circle Ci.

I also tried to do a `aws s3 ls` before the create-invalidation command, and it works fine on circle ci.

I'm losing my mind...

Anyone has a clue ?

Julien

Answer (score 0):

This can happen as a result of having white space in the values of your access key or secret, I would check to make the values in Circle CI don't have any surrounding whitespace. See https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/issues/3313 for another case of this.

Comment: thanks. just tried removing all the variable and resetting them. Same error unfortunetaly.